# Посоветуйте кроссплатформенные библиотеки для создания движка для 2D-игры

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, поиск-библиотек

Нужен не готовый фреймворк типа юнити, а библиотека, реализующая только отрисовку основных примитивов: точки, линии, текстуры и т.п..

При этом библиотека не должна быть "заброшенной" и желательно чтобы API был поновее `C++03`. Если у библиотеки `C`-API, то не должно быть привязки к конкретным типам для координат точек, например. То есть желательно, чтобы была поддержка шаблонов.

Знаю про `SFML`, но разработка слишком медленная (до сих пор на `C++03`), нет поддержки шаблонов для типов точек (обязательно `float` координаты), но по функционалу надо что-то типа неё.

Comment: [OpenGL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL#:~:text=OpenGL%20(Open%20Graphics%20Library)%20%E2%80%94,%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E%20%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E%20%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83.)?

Comment: @timur спасибо, почитаю про C++ API этой библиотеки и узнаю, подходит ли она мне

Comment: @timur а она точно кроссплатформенная? В [первом туториале в поисковике](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/opengl/HowTo_OpenGL_C.html) инклюдится `windows.h`

Comment: @vadim это графический API, оно окошко создавать не умеет, с вводом не работает и т.д., поэтому нужны дополнительные средства.

Comment: @Croessmah понял, спасибо, тогда такое не очень подходит, надо что-то вроде функций `template <class T> drawPoint(lib::Point<T, T> point)`

Comment: В SDL есть такое.

Comment: @eanmos спасибо, посмотрел эту библиотеку, похоже что она написана на `C` и жёстко привязана к типам https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Point

Comment: Проще будет написать свою обертку к SDL, чем искать библиотеку с такими строгими требованиями.

Comment: https://github.com/libSDL2pp/libSDL2pp

Comment: [OpenGL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL#:~:text=OpenGL%20(Open%20Graphics%20Library)%20—,двумерную%20и%20трёхмерную%20компьютерную%20графику.)? [github.com/libSDL2pp/libSDL2pp](https://github.com/libSDL2pp/libSDL2pp)

Comment: OpenGL это не библиотека и не фраймворк. Это спецификация программного интерфейса. На каждой платформе существуют свои конкретные программные реализации.